# Choosing \firstmark and \botmark with \leftmark?

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm very new to LaTeX, and I'm having a terribly difficult time understanding the marking system. I'm not really grasping what The LaTeX Companion and the fancyhdr manual are saying.

I'm creating a book type document that contains chapters and sections, and I want `\thechapter`.`\thesection` on the corner of each header.

Because it's a book format, each chapter begins on its own page, and that's how I want it. However, there are multiple sections on a page for certain pages.

I want the *first* section on the *even* pages to be displayed for `\thesection`, and I want the *last* section on the *odd* pages to be displayed for `\thesection`.

As of right now, I can only get LaTeX to display the *last* section on any page, whether it's even or odd. Here's the current code and a picture showing what I mean.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\nouppercase\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\nouppercase\leftmark}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}{\markboth{\thechapter}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}{\markboth{\thesection}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Header Test}
    \section{Sec1}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Sec2}
    \lipsum[3-4]
    \section{Sec3}
    \lipsum[5]
    \section{Sec4}
    \lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

[image: gah]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first new section rather than the section continued from the previous page, I think you just need to use *first* marks rather than *top* marks. This code is adapted (slightly) from Werner's answer:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titleps}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{
  \sethead[\firsttitlemarks\bfseries\thesection][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
  {}{}{\bottitlemarks\bfseries\thesection}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setfoot[\thepage][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
  {}{}{\thepage}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setheadrule{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Header Test}
  \section{Sec1}
  \lipsum[1]
  \section{Sec2}
  \lipsum[3-4]
  \section{Sec3}
  \lipsum[5]
  \section{Sec4}
  \lipsum[7]
  \chapter{New Chapter}
  \section{Sec5}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Sec6}
  \lipsum[6]
  \section{Sec7}
  \lipsum[8-9]
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

[image: fancy headers]

The only case in which I can reproduce chapters without headers is one in which there is no `\section` command on the initial page of the chapter. In this case, I do get a header, but it is just a line with no mark for the chapter or section. Since there is no section, this makes sense. However, you might want to have the chapter marked in this case.

If so, you can try this:

```
\renewpagestyle{plain}{
  \sethead[\firsttitlemarks\bfseries\ifnum\value{section}=0 \thechapter\else\thesection\fi][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
  {}{}{\bottitlemarks\bfseries\ifnum\value{section}=0 \thechapter\else\thesection\fi}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setfoot[\thepage][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
  {}{}{\thepage}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setheadrule{0.4pt}
}
```

[image: chapter only]

## EDIT

I am not sure why issuing `\tableofcontents` seems to blank the headers. However, since you are using `titlesec`, you could use the following method which utilises the conditionals from that package. I'm not sure what should happen on the contents page itself. This puts the title of the contents into the header since there is no chapter number here. (Or, rather, the number is 0.)

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{
  \sethead[\firsttitlemarks\bfseries\ifthesection{\thesection}{\ifthechapter{\thechapter}{\chaptertitle}}][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
  {}{}{\bottitlemarks\bfseries\ifthesection{\thesection}{\ifthechapter{\thechapter}{\chaptertitle}}}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setfoot[\thepage][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
  {}{}{\thepage}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setheadrule{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Header Test}
  \section{Sec1}
  \lipsum[1]
  \section{Sec2}
  \lipsum[3-4]
  \section{Sec3}
  \lipsum[5]
  \section{Sec4}
  \lipsum[7]
  \chapter{New Chapter}
  \section{Sec5}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Sec6}
  \lipsum[6]
  \section{Sec7}
  \lipsum[8-9]
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
  \chapter{GAH}
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \chapter{New Chapter AAAA}
  \section{Sec5}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Sec6}
  \lipsum[6]
  \section{Sec7}
  \lipsum[8-9]
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
  \chapter{GAH1}
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \chapter{New CHAPTER AAAAA}
  \section{Sec5}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Sec6}
  \lipsum[6]
  \section{Sec7}
  \lipsum[8-9]
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Gah, I was able to get this to work in the test document, but I'm still not able to get it to work in the actual document. Not sure why. EDIT: Aha! The problem definitely has something to do with `\tableofcontents`. I reproduced the problem by using it: http://pastebin.com/yqfb0fkz

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley See edited answer. I don't know why it doesn't work but this seems to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of answering your direct question, I'd answer it with an alternative suggestion. That is, using [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps).

Using *switches* like `\toptitlemarks`, `\firsttitlemarks` or `\bottitlemarks` you can extract the information for the specific section in a dictionary-style format. Below I've redefined the `plain` page style (just like you did with [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)) setting the header and footer accordingly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titleps}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{
  \sethead[\toptitlemarks\bfseries\thesection][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
    {}{}{\bottitlemarks\bfseries\thesection}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setfoot[\thepage][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
    {}{}{\thepage}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setheadrule{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Header Test}
\section{Sec1}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec2}
\lipsum[3-4]
\section{Sec3}
\lipsum[5]
\section{Sec4}
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```

The use of `titleps` is eased when reading [`titleps` for `fancyhdr` users](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/titleps_fancyhdr.html). The discussion on dictionary-style headings is mentioned in the [`titleps` documentation](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/archive/titleps.pdf) (section **4 Marks**).

Comment: I tried this, but I also use `titlesec` in the document. I'm getting an 'Incompatible package' error. Am I unable to use both?

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley: [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) should be fully-compatible with [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) as its written by the same author. However, don't use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) as well.

Comment: I figured out that I can use them both if I don't use the titleps package, but just do `\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}`. This works, and it looks like titleps will work best.

But, now I'm running in to two other problems. First, the header doesn't even show up on some of the first pages of a new chapter. Second, on some pages that have sections from the last page, that last section is displayed in the header instead of the first section of that page. Are these things that can even be fixed?

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley I'm a big fan of `fancyhdr` and use it almost all the time. However, if you are using `titlesec`, you really would be best advised to use `titleps` and `titlesec` ***without*** `fancyhdr` as you are much more likely to find things work cooperatively rather than antagonistically.

Comment: @cfr I'm using it without `fancyhdr`. So far, it's a bit easier to use and I'm liking it. I'm just running in to the problem now that the header doesn't show up on the first page of some new chapters, and also that the mark isn't the first *new* section on a page, but the first section on the page *from the last page*. If I could fix these things, I'd be a happy camper!