# "CONTENTS" in header issue

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, formatting, header-footer, luatex

I am currently using a header on my document that should do one of a few things.

If the current page is before any chapters or sections are defined, the header should only contain a number.

If there are any sections or chapters defined before the current page, the name of the last defined section / chapter should be in the header.

There are two excpetions to this rule. If there is a new chapter, there should be no header on the page or table of contents.

If there is a title page, there should be no footer / header.

This works great. However, when a table of contents is added, all the headers  become prefixed with `CONTENTS`. How can I prevent the headers being prefixed with `CONTENTS` without affecting any of the header functionality that was described above.

There is also a case when there is no section or title in the header, but there is a table of contents, the header is consists of `CONTENTSCONTENTS`.

If it makes a difference, I am building using LuaTex on the latest version of TexLive (downloaded today)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%Header / Footer info
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

%Define the header / footer
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\topmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
hello
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\section{Paragraphs 1 - 10}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum :)}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Paragraphs 6 - 10}
\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Paragraphs 11 - 15}
\lipsum[11-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\topmark` doesn't work correctly in LaTeX. Afaik, the only way to get correct heads with top marks is with (my) `titleps` (see sec. 5 of its manual).

Comment: @JavierBezos Hey, I just saw your comment. I actually tried to use your `titleps` (I really like how I can use it by the way. I prefer the formatting to fancyhdr's) but I still had the issue of contents being included. At the time I was using similar code to the code found in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208352/92999)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I am too new to LaTeX to know if this is the correct way, it certainly seems a bit to "hacky" to be correct, but it works for me.

The way I succeeded was to use two defined `fancyhdr` styles, as well as the plain style, and to keep switching the page style at different stages to produce the look I wanted.

At the start of the document, the plain page style was used. Then if there was any text but no chapters / sections defined, a separate `fancyhdr` was used that simply contained the current page number in the header.

Finally the `fancyhdr` style from the original code was used. However, the `renrewcommand` for the `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` was declared after the page style had been set to this style to force the `CONTENTS` not to be included in the header.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%Header / Footer info
\fancypagestyle{NormalFancy}{ %Style for when there is at least
                              %one previous chapter or section
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\topmark}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{FancyNoSectionChapter}{ %Style for when there are no 
                                        %previous chapters or sections
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
hello
\end{titlepage}
\pagestyle{plain} %Set this here to remove the header and footer
                  %at the start of the document

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

%Set the page style before any chapters or sections are defined
\pagestyle{FancyNoSectionChapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage

%Set the page style to the normal style before the start of 
%the page with the first defined section / chapter
\thispagestyle{FancyNoSectionChapter}
\pagestyle{NormalFancy} %Make sure the page with the first defined 
                        %section / chapter still has the `FancyNoSectionChapter` style
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}} %Redefine how the chapter
                                               %looks so there are no numbers
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}} %Redefine how the section
                                               %looks so there are no numbers

\section{Paragraphs 1 - 10}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum :)}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Paragraphs 6 - 10}
\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Paragraphs 11 - 15}
\lipsum[11-15]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking is how to get rid of the header "CONTENTS", which is being carried over from the TOC into the beginning of the main text.  That header is present because it is being held as a mark.

You therefore want to obliterate all existing marks when you begin the main text.  The easiest way to do this is to add this command immediately after the `\clearpage` that closes out the contents:

```
\markboth{}{}
```